# how can I render pug(jade) to html in npm scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pug

I am trying to build my package.json file, and I am having a difficult time when it comes to writing scripts.

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", 
"build-css":"node-sass --output-style compressed -o build/styles src/styles", 
"pugtohtml": "npm pug -D index.pug"  
},
```

this doesn't work

I've installed the pug package and now I want to automate the task using just npm can you please help me with that and I would appreciate it if you give me tips and resources of how to learn writing scripts and automating tasks using just npm, thank you!

Comment: Would it just be `pug -D index.pug` instead of `npm pug -D index.pug`?

Comment: you dont have to call npm within npm, just do `pug [args]`

Answer (score 2):

You must write the task like this

```
"pugtohtml": "pug --output-style compressed -o dist/html/ assets/pug/*.pug"
```

Comment: it's works for me but, I need to install 'npm' and 'npm-cli'. It's good to remember that!! XD!

Comment: To run it without installing it globally, you can reference pug from node_modules. `"pugtohtml":"./node_modules/.bin/pug -P -o public/ Views/index.pug"`

Comment: npx can be used to run it from local installed deps, avoiding global.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the command line client is required to use this with NPM scripts.

Per the [Pug NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug#installation):

> #### Package
>
> `npm install pug`
>
> #### Command Line
>
> After installing the latest version of Node.js, install with:
>
> `npm install pug-cli -g`

---

I'm using `npm install pug-cli --save-dev` instead because I prefer packages to be installed local to the project I'm working on, but YMMV.

If you're into the global (`-g`) thing, you might not need the `pug-cli` package for command line handling, and you could possibly use the other solutions mentioned here.